# Standard deviation of a product

Tags: standard-deviation

I have two independent variables X and Y, with known SDs. I want to calculate

SD(k*Y*X^3), where k is a constant.

How?

Best, J

Comment: I guess the two variables can be assumed to be Gaussians? Or .. ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know more than just the standard deviations.

You can do manipulations like this:

\begin{eqnarray}
Var(X^3Y) &=& E(X^6Y^2) - E(X^3Y)^2\\
&=& E(X^6)E(Y^2) - [E(X^3) E(Y)]^2\\
&=& E(X^6)E(Y^2) - E(X^3)^2E(Y^2) + E(X^3)^2E(Y^2) - [E(X^3) E(Y)]^2\\
&=& Var(X^3) E(Y^2) + E(X^3) Var(Y)
\end{eqnarray}

which might be of some value in some situations.